# pluggable function in theme, to be overridden by plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, themes, pluggable

Is it possible to add a function in functions.php like this:

```
// ACF
    if ( !function_exists('get_field') ) {
        function get_field() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and then let plugins that creates that function override my theme function? In this case I'm using Advanced Custom Fields, and id like to have a fail-safe, that won't create "function does not exist" errors, in case the plugin gets deactivated. So i'd like my theme to have a fallback for that same function.

Im assuming i might need to hook in somewhere, but I'm don't really know when.

If i do what i've done above then it won't allow me to activate Advanced Custom Fields, because now the functions already exists (in my theme).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ( !function_exists('get_field') && $_REQUEST['action'] != 'activate' )
```

This will prevent your function being defined for the run where a plugin is actually being activated.